# Redirect entire form after server-side validation

Tags: php, forms, laravel, cross-domain

So I have a form with both client side and server-side validation, but the server-side is much more important because we have stuff like csrf protection. The form MUST come to our server first, then head off to a second server.

I need to be able to submit the form to my server, run my validations, then if it passes, send the ENTIRE form to another page. -- I mean with the action attribute of the form, all of the fields, everything. It should behave as though the original action of the form was the redirected domain.

Is this possible with perhaps curl, or maybe I can dynamically create a new form from the values of the original and send that off to the other domain with a POST header?

Should have mentioned: I don't have access to the other server, it is a 3rd party.

Comment: What are you using for the form validation. Your database?

Comment: Yeah,  but that can possibly be removed. The biggest thing is CSRF to avoid spam

Comment: why dont you save the data to database then get it from the other server?

Comment: anyway if you are sending data do another laravel app on another server, try using cURL ( `$posteddata = Request::all();` ) then send all posted fields  to an api on the second server(which will store data somewhere (db) and after the send success , redirect to the wanted route in the second server, the method in the second server will get data from db and fill form data with it (or whatever you want to do ) - THIS IS WHAT I HAVE ON MY MIND, i dont know if there is a better way

Answer (score 0):

You can do your validation in the same page then insert it to your database and redirect the current page to the other page and retrieve the data for example:

```
if(isset($_POST)){
    // here you assign variables to the post values like:
    $name = $_POST['name'];

    //then you run your validation from the database
    // assuming $con to be your db connection variable
    $query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM table WHERE (blah blah blah)");
    if(mysqli_num_row ==1){
        if(mysqli_query($con, " INSERT INTO table VALUES(blah blah blah)")){
            //then you use the header to redirect the page to the next page
            header(location: 'path/to/page');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: again, the second server is a third party; they don't have access to our database

Answer (score -1):

You can pass your variables using cookies or sessions on another page and use them.
Suppose your form name is 
`FIRST_FORM_VALIDATE` and this is on some page `FIRST_FORM_PAGE`.

Now take the user input on `FIRST_FORM_PAGE` and send this data using POST method to `FIRST_FORM_VALIDATE`. Here you can validate your data on server if data is correct, store all inputs in session variables like this-

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['form_input1']=$_POST['form_input1'];
```

And so on, store all variables. Now you can use these variables on another page wherever you want to validate these. And after completing your validation, destroy the session variables.

EDIT- If you are sending your data to another server and want to prevent CSRF, then best way to do that store these entires in temporary database and then access it on another server using remote database connection.

Comment: dude is that even possible? he wants to send data from a server to another! can you do that using sessions?

Comment: That will do on same server, for remote server I have edited my answer.

Comment: Try to avoid GLOBALS, Instead you may use ```Session::put()```, Instead of $_POST use ```Input`` or ```Request``` in Controller Method, 

The correct answer, Submit that formal normally, Validate the Request, if it passes according to the requirements, use ```GuzzleHttp```

Comment: i know that dosent work only in same server (its just a polite way to say thats wrong) and yea your edit makes sense ,thats what i said in my comments already but you way is a bit simpler ( i  thought like this, send data to an api, api stores data on db of the second server then the method on first server will redirect to the second server if post success , there is no shared DB between to servers)

Comment: @AchrafKhouadja To be honest, I don't see any reason to store data into DB or somewhere, The workflow would be like this ```Client -> First Server -> Second Server``` Client submit form, (In controller handle the request and take input from request then submit to the API)

Comment: that would be simpler and that makes a lot of sense , but im asuming he needs the data (because **usualy** form data will be stored) (and the db part comes after the api , i mean the api will store to a db)